# Thanks Use in submit application

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing an application where people will submit a filled forms. I would like to give a success message after submit. So I compiled three sentences which is more appropriate, need your guidance

1. Thanks for your application.
2. Thanking you for your application.
3. Thanking You for showing trust on us.

Regards
VK

Comment: You don't show trust *on* someone. That's not English. Likewise, you don't capitalize *you* in English. This is really basic stuff. I suggest you hire a professional copywriter. Your command of the language is vastly insufficient. Do not write anything yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first one is natural English. Personally, I would recommend saying:

> Thank you for submitting your application.

It's a very natural style of success message.

"Thanks" isn't incorrect, but is a little informal for this sort of use. For a program for submitting application forms, it's probably better to be a little more formal, and so "thank you" is better than "thanks".

"Thanking you" is strange. If we thank someone, we will always say "thank you". It's a set expression. "Thanking" is only used as a verb for "to show appreciation", for example:

> When I saw him, he was thanking her for helping him.

Also, we don't "show trust on", we rather "show trust in". In this context, rather than "show", "place your trust in us" would be more natural. To "place your trust in [someone]" means to do something that relies on the other person not to break your trust. For example, trusting you not to lose/misuse their application.

This isn't as common as just thanking them for submitting their application, however.

Comment: I would prefer "Thank you" but "Thanks" would be OK if you want to project a very informal image. And I suspect the use of the present progressive ("Thanking you") may be a feature of Indian English.

Comment: Agreed. For most programming, especially for submitting application forms, using more formal language instead of less is probably better.